# How can I use timers/promises from Node 16 in a Typescript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm

In [Node 16 release, there's new timers/promises API](https://nodejs.medium.com/node-js-16-available-now-7f5099a97e70) that I want to use. I installed `Node 16` with `NVM` and switched to it:

```
$ nvm use       
Found '/Users/golergka/Projects/my-project/.nvmrc' with version <16>
Now using node v16.0.0 (npm v7.10.0)
```

And even added engines to my `package.json`:

```
"engines": { "node": ">=16" }
```

I wasn't sure if I needed to install version `16` of `@types/node`, but I tried (without success):

```
npm install --save-dev @types/node@16
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @types/node@16.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
```

For now, I have `^14.14.41` installed.

And finally, I tried to import `setTimeout` in my `Typescript` file:

```js
import { setTimeout } from 'timers/promises'
```

But got an error:

```
Cannot find module 'timers/promises' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Does it not run or does your IDE just complain? That error just looks like a ts warning because the types file doesn’t know about new 16 stuff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has been published 3 days ago, in `@types/node`. Just run `npm install --save-dev @types/node@latest`, or `yarn add --dev @types/node@latest`. The version is 0.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the node types are outdated, you can only turn off the error with ts ignore